# Помогите убрать часть url, чтобы оно корректно открывалось

Tags: php, cms

Есть вот такой url:
`http://site.org/page.php?page=test`

выводится в php файл при помощи:
`<? echo BASE_URL; ?>/admin/delete.php?id=<? echo e($page['id']); ?>`

скажите простой способ как сделать url такого-типа:
`http://site.org/test`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820723/how-to-get-base-url-with-php вариантов на любой вкус...

Comment: @kroder Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.